# Does this thing I'm calling 'the operationalization of $x$' have an accepted name?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, category-theory, terminology, computer-science

Given a set $X$ and an element $x \in X$, we can turn $x$ into a function denoted $\tilde{x}$ as follows: for any set $Y$ and any function $f : X \rightarrow Y$, define $$\tilde{x}(f) = f(x).$$

For my purposes, which are a little too complicated to really describe here, it would be useful to have a name for this process, at least for use in the privacy of my own mind and/or notebook. Furthermore, since this process turns a mere value or element of $X$ into an 'operator' in its own right, I'm tempted to call this process 'operationalization.' So in particular, $\tilde{x}$ is the *operationalization* of $x$.

> **Question.** Does this thing I'm calling 'the operationalization of $x$' have an accepted name?

Comment: I'm not sure if this has a name, but it happens all the time in functional analysis. In that context, you would be referring to an element in the dual.

Comment: @par, true. So perhaps calling this the 'dual' of $x$ is okay. Its a bit shorter than 'operationalization', at least :)

Comment: I know that in ring theory we have a substitution operator denoted by $\varphi _a$, which does exactly that: $\varphi _a (f) = f(a)$. I have seen this only when $f$ is a polynomial but I'm sure you can expand the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of [functional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space), the map 
$$
\Phi: A \to (\Bbb F)^{\Bbb F^A}\\
\Phi:x \mapsto (f \mapsto f(x))
$$
is called the "*evaluation map*".

Comment: Isn't $\Phi(x)$ called the evaluation map (at $x$), rather than $\Phi$ itself? (I'm not an analyst so maybe conventions are different there.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi bases on the language of the Wiki page, $\Phi$ itself is referred to as the evaluation map

Comment: A related notion is that of the [Gelfand transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation#Gelfand_representation_of_a_commutative_Banach_algebra) and the more general [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality).

Comment: Well in the context of rigid monoidal categories the evaluation map is $\operatorname{ev} : X \otimes X^* \to I$, in any case. So this isn't universal terminology. (It looks more natural to me, but again, not an analyst.)

Comment: Is the function $f \mapsto f(x)$ ever referred to as the 'evaluator of $x$' or anything like that?

Comment: @goblin how about "the evaluation at $x$"?  I don't know if it's used, but I think it's clear enough to be understood.

Comment: I like it. $\;\!$

Answer (score 5):

It's called the canonical map into the double dual. It does not have another name that I know of. In a monoidal category with duals (I'm being vague), the uncurried version of it, $\operatorname{ev} : X \otimes X^* \to I$, is called evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

In linear algebra the double-dual comes to mind, but the general term that's most relevant is "evaluation map". One somewhat common notation is $\mathrm{ev}_{x}(f)=f(x)$. Either ev (your ~) is the evaluation map, or each $\mathrm{ev}_{x}$ is the evaluation map at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at $x \in X$ as a map $x \colon 1 \to X$, the operator $\tilde x$ is precisely the natural transformation given by co-Yoneda's embedding
$$ \mathsf{Set}(X,-) \stackrel{\mathsf{Set}(x,-)} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}(1,-) \simeq \mathrm{id}_{\mathsf{Set}} $$

So you could call it the restriction along $x$, or precomposition by $x$, and denote it $x^\ast$.